# What ammo does a launcher-type regimental favored weapon come with?

Tags: warhammer-40k, only-war

In Only War, two classes, the Weapons Specialist and the Heavy Gunner, can start the game equipped with Launcher-type weapons.

The errata has clarified that class equipment comes with three 'clips'. What does that mean for Launchers, however? Does the grenade launcher come with 18 (I think) frag grenades? 18 krak grenades? 6 frag, 6 krak, 6 smoke?

Or the missile launcher: If the Heavy takes it without it being the regimental weapon, he gets 5 frag missiles. Does he simply get 8 if it is the regimental weapon or does he get 5 frag and three others? Or can he choose between getting 5 frag missiles and getting three?

Comment: I don't think the rules are clear as to RAW that i could find; however when in doubt give the PCs more ammo, and then add more creatures to use it against if its an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### It Doesn't Say

The rules are not explicit as to which kind of grenades a launcher comes equipped with.  To keep in theme with the typical rules for issuance of Munitorum gear, i'd roll a 50% chance of Frag grenades, a 40% chance of Krak, 5% chance of Smoke, and 5% chance of Stun.

If you wanted to be nice, you'd just give them a mixture, probably 2 clips frag one clip krak.

Comment: So, you'd give them three clips, and roll for each or how do you intend the % chances to work?

Otherwise, I think you are right.

Comment: That is, I'll accept your answer soon, if no one else comes up with anything massively better. Which is unlikely :)